# Screen readers not reading bootstrap-select dropdown options

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using the [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) jquery plugin in forms on my site for multiple select dropdowns. Everything funtions as it should, however screen readers don't read the dropdown options. If I test screen readers on the bootstrap-select examples on their site it reads the options fine, but not on my forms and I am using the exact same markup:

```
<div>
   <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Barbecue</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Any idea what could be blocking screen readers from reading the dropdown options and why it is working one place but not another?